# How to turn this source code into a actual software

Tags: oracle, compilation

So I have this source code of a software which is probably developed in oracle.
Can anybody tell me how can I turn this into an actual software?
I am a newbie. 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqGAW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Those are Oracle Forms (.fmx) and Reports (.rep) executables, as well as a Menu module (.mmx). In order to run them, you'd first have to know which Oracle Developer Suite version it is; might be anything from at least 4.5 over 6i/9i/10g or even later; who knows, they all share same extensions.

Forms up to 6i are client-server; later versions are web-based so you'd have to install IAS (Internet Application Server) or WebLogic server; none of those installations is trivial so - if you can't even recognize what you have, you'd rather not do that on your own - consider hiring a consultant.

Once you manage to set it up, you'd run the .mmx file as it looks as the menu for that application.

However, it's not that simple - in order to run such an application, you have to establish connection to the database, i.e. a schema that contains tables used by this application. There's the "Database" folder - maybe it contains some more useful info, perhaps export file (.dmp), maybe even .dbf files ... can't tell just by looking at the icon.

It might be enough if all tables are owned by the same user; otherwise, application might fail because of missing dependencies.

Finally, I think that your best option is to find out someone who actually *knows* what it is, which development software was used to create those forms & reports and then see if something can be done. It would be simpler/easier if you had .fmb and .rdf (or .jsp) files instead of executables as you could edit them.